# Automatically Updatable GEE App

Tags: google-earth-engine, update

I'm looking to make a Google Earth Engine App that automatically updates on a regular basis as new satellite imagery comes in for a given dataset. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this easily from within the GEE code editor / 'publish app' menu – is it possible to interact with an already-published GEE App via the GEE API?

One typically specifies a time frame for resources used in the GEE code editor, e.g.:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('TRMM/3B42')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-03-15', '2019-03-16'));
```

For automatic updates, the updated time & date would need to be specified in the image query code.

Automatic updates would be useful to create, for instance, an app that displays latest weather changes / cloud cover movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want the most recent imagery, then a very simple option would be to, instead of specifying a date range, ask for the most recent images, limited to a reasonable number (depending on how frequent the images in the collection are, and how much area they cover).

```js
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('TRMM/3B42')
  .limit({
    max: 100,
    property: 'system:time_start',
    ascending: false
  });
```

However, this is not very fast because this query ends up reading the entire image collection and sorting it. I mention it because it's “foolproof” and would work well for small collections.

---

Instead, we could use the current time (as understood by the app's user's computer) to define a range:

```js
var endDate = ee.Date(Date.now());
var startDate = endDate.advance(-2, 'day');
print(startDate, endDate);
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('TRMM/3B42').filterDate(startDate, endDate);
```

(Note that I wrote `Date.now()`, not `ee.Date.now()`; this is calling a built-in *JavaScript* function, not an Earth Engine API function.)

However, if you run this code it will return no images, because TRMM/3B42 has no data from the past 2 days. This strategy requires knowing where to set the start date to get a reasonable number of images. For consistently updated datasets, this should work well.

---

A further elaboration might be to make the time range adaptive: write something like

```js
ee.ImageCollection('...')
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    .size()
    .evaluate(function (size) {
        // think about the size here
    })
```

to find out *how many images are in a candidate date range*, then adjust the range up or down so that you can produce a map with a reasonable number of images. This is tricky because it would involve writing an “asynchronous loop” — waiting for evaluate()'s response and deciding whether to evaluate() another attempt with a different range. Make sure it can't get stuck trying again repeatedly.